# Polars save partitions with Unicode symbols

Tags: python, python-polars

I am saving a .parquet file with partitions using polars.
Polars adds square brackets to the partition name for some reason, it looks like this -
`[ "my_partition" ]`.
Accordingly, the partitions are named like some nonsense

```
columns = 'animals' 
df = pl.read_parquet('test.parquet')
df.write_parquet(
            './my_path/',
            use_pyarrow=True,
            pyarrow_options={"partition_cols": [columns]}
        )
```

This is what it looks like in the folder:

[image: this is what it looks like in the folder]

In jupyter:

[image: it's result in jupyter]

how can this be fixed?

UPDATE. Example code:

```
output_path = './data_parquet'
data = {'animals':['cat','dog','cat','dog','cat','dog','cat','dog']}
pl.DataFrame(data).write_parquet(
            output_path,
            use_pyarrow=True,
            pyarrow_options={"partition_cols": ['animals']}
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is no actual problem with the writing of partitioned parquet files. However, you don't actually want the extra `[ "`, `" ]` surrounding the strings in the *animal* column.

You can remove them before writing the partitioned parquet as follows.

```py
df.with_columns(pl.col("animal").str.split('"').list.get(1))
```

Subsequently, the folders for the partitioned parquet file should have the expected structure.

Comment: Not really, my jupyter examples are the result.
I've added sample code

Comment: @DenisLvov For me, your example code produces the correct results (folders named *animals=cat*, *animals=dog* in a folder *data_parquet*). Could you also share the output corresponding to the example code? What version of polars and pyarrow are you using?

Comment: polars '0.20.4'
pyarrow '15.0.0'

Comment: no way!
In jupyter pyarraw version '11.0.0' and that's why partitions were created so crookedly

I apologize, it's my fault.

Comment: Yes, the problem was that the pyarrow version in jyputer was 11.0.0 - it saved crookedly
thank you